# C# Create Control From a String Value

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Hi Can I create a Control from String Value
Like

from
"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" create control

Comment: Your question is not clear to answer.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use reflection:

```
var textBoxType = typeof(Control).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox", true);
var textBox = Activator.CreateInstance(textBoxType);
```

Comment: Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Its true,working wonderfull.i have one question too.I define  textbox but how can i change textbox text or size from string like           "Text"

Comment: @deneme, you could once again use reflection on the newly created instance: `textBoxType.GetProperty("Text").SetValue(textBox, "Hello World", null);`. I would recommend you reading more about reflection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do like this :

```
var controlType = typeof(Control);
        var type = controlType
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => controlType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && 
                        t.Namespace == "System.Windows.Forms"
                        t.Name == "ControlName"
            ).FirstOrDefault();

var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type );
```

This answer is because of your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var type = assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox");
var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Can't test it yet. But it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Type t = Type.GetType( yourTypeStingHere);

 ConstructorInfo info = t.GetConstructor( new Type[] { } );
 object instance = info.Invoke(new object[]{} )
```