# How can i make form action and design from external file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Let's take an example of what i want. If i have a form in C# and i want this form design and action varies according to some files say XML files sometimes this form has a picture box and button do something, sometimes this form has some labels, buttons , panels do something else according to the external file given to the program. may these files has form styles, controls, action??

How is it possible to do that and if it is possible how to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading from an Xml file, this can be achieved.

You need to have a FormDesignManager which should be able to parse the xml and create the form put all the controls and return the form.

```
publci class FormDesignManager 
{
    public static Form CreateForm(string xmlPath)
    {
        var form = new Form();
        //design the controls for the form
        //you can get System.Windows.Forms.TextBox or any other controls from the xml
        var control = typeof(Control).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox", true);
        var textBox = Activator.CreateInstance(textBoxType);
        return form;
    }
}
```

Please, see this [C# Create Control From a String Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788080/c-sharp-create-control-from-a-string-value)

Comment: you mean i have to handle every case. if i write textbox in xml i create xml also for other controls??
what about doing specific action like button do something and that action not known and written in external file?

Comment: You can do this if you consider several controls only. Otherwise, you can use reflection to crate the control on the fly. Reflection makes it easy to create the objects without knowing anything about the object itself.

Comment: Excuse me, because i didn't know about reflection well just a name :D . So did you mean i can design my form with it's actions and convert it to dll file. then from my program use this dll file and know what it contains and execute it. Is that true?